# Getting null pointer exception while getting image from another activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have made a Custom List View in android. And i want that Whenever list view click event called it goes into another activity and the data which is on that list will be displayed on new activity. Below code is my Like MainActivity(Here named as ListofWorkers) which have also Layout file.

```
package com.example.dispatchmedemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.dispatchmedemo.CustomListViewAdapter;
import com.example.dispatchmedemo.RowItem;

public class ListofWorkers extends Activity {

    public static final String[] name = new String[] { "ABC",
            "YZA", "ASDSA", "ASD", "ASD", "SDFS" };

    public static final String[] landmarks = new String[] {
            "AFDDF",
            "ADF", "ADFD",
            "ADFAD", "ADFADF", "ADFAD" };

    public static final String[] rates = new String[] {
        "100",
        "500", "300",
        "400", "120", "600" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;
    Button responseSubmit;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listof_workers);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], name[i], landmarks[i], rates[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_single, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                    View view,int position, long id) {

                Intent i = new Intent(ListofWorkers.this, WorkerProfile.class);

                i.putExtra("name", name);

                i.putExtra("landmarks", landmarks);

                i.putExtra("rates", rates);

                i.putExtra("image", images);

                i.putExtra("position", position);

                startActivity(i);
              }

        });
    }
    }
```

Now this is my another activity "WorkerProfile" where i got name,landmarks and rates but only in image, i got null pointer exception, what i have put in TOAST.

```
package com.example.dispatchmedemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WorkerProfile extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtname;
    TextView txtlandmark;
    TextView txtrate;
    ImageView imgpro;
    String[] name;
    String[] landmarks;
    String[] rate;
    int[] images;
    int position;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_worker_profile);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");

        name = i.getStringArrayExtra("name");

        landmarks = i.getStringArrayExtra("landmarks");

        rate = i.getStringArrayExtra("rates");

        images  = i.getIntArrayExtra("image");


        txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txtlandmark = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtrate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        imgpro = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ActivityWorkerProflePic);


        txtname.setText(name[position]);
        txtlandmark.setText(landmarks[position]);
        txtrate.setText(rate[position]);

        imgpro.setImageResource(images[position]);
       }
}
```

Comment: Where you get the NPE? Mark the line and add the whole stactrce from you logCat

Comment: Check at which line you are getting error?

Comment: use the debug tool to check what is null

Comment: I have put try and catch in Second Activity named as "WorkerProfile" at bottom at line " imgpro.setImageResource(images[position]); " and there i have put TOAST which gives the exception message in application. There exception of NPE shows. @Jens

Comment: Maybe `imgpro` is null or `images` is null or `images[position]` can you verify which value is null?

Comment: @RonakJoshi : See the comment I added to the answer from Ravi Bhayani. It explains why `putExtra(...)` worked for your `Integer[]` but why calling `getIntArrayExtra(...)` failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are passing integer as an object defined by **Integer** which is a wrapper class.

And at the receiver activity you are retrieving it as an array of primitive type(**int**). That is why you are getting Null pointer exception.

Please change the below code,

```
public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };
```

to,

```
public static final int[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };
```

Hope It will help.

Comment: I'll explain why this answer is correct. The `Integer` wrapper class extends the Java `Number` class which implements `Serializable`. Further to this, all Java arrays are themselves objects which implement `Serializable`. Consequently, calling `putExtra(...)` for `Integer[]` doesn't call the `putExtra(String name, int[] value)` method and instead it calls the `putExtra(String name, Serializable value)` method. An alternative fix would have been to declare `Integer[] images` in the WorkerProfile `Activity` and use `i.getSerializableExtra("image")` instead of `i.getIntArrayExtra("image")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
bundel.putIntArray("image",images);

Intent intent = new Intent(this,next.class)
intent.putExtras(bundel);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in nect.class use like:

```
Integer img[] = getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("image");
```

Comment: But i have int array of images which is not supported "bundel.putStringArray("image",images);"  @KrupaPatel

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Put images array as IntegerArrayList in sending intent

```
i.putIntegerArrayListExtra("image", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(images)))
```

then get like

```
ArrayList<Integer> images  = i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("image");
```

the use it like

```
imgpro.setImageResource(images.get(position));
```